# Grammar of a non-regular language

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

Given the alphabet $Λ = \{a, b\}$ and this non-regular language:

$$L=\{aba^nb^ma^n|n,m>0\}$$

what's the best way to generate the grammar?  Every string has to start with $ab$, then we have $aba$ and this part has to have the same number of $a$. In words that is clear, but I'm stuck; should I first consider the fixed part $ab$, or is better to produce the $a^nb^ma^n$ part and then add the $ab$? I need a method basically.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should think of this language as all words of the form
$$
xa^nya^n,
$$
where $x=ab$ and $y \in b^*$. You can now modify a grammar for $a^nb^n$ to generate your language.